# Installing Matplotlib in Openshift; freetypelib dependency

Tags: python, matplotlib, virtualenv, openshift

I am trying to install Matplotlib in a Python cartridge in Openshift with `pip`. it fails due to a dependency on `freetypelib`.

Is there a way to make Matplotlib work in that environment?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain what you mean by "it fails". Please include **full** tracebacks (if they exist) and a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is as known bug in 1.4.0, it fails in the freetype-dev headers are not installed.  This has been fixed on the maintenance branch and will be included in the 1.4.1 release (end of the month).

Answer (score 0):

Check if libfreetype is installed (try "locate libfreetype"), if you find some output then you may have look at this post https://www.openshift.com/forums/express/is-libjpeg-available#comment-35344
If not install libfreetype. Let me know if you have any problems installing libfreetype